# read mail out of maildir direcory with correct encoding and use in bash

Tags: bash, character-encoding, maildir

I'm trying to implement some sort of spamreport for my Mail Server. Mails are sorted by sieve and are all in one folder called Spam. I loop through the folder with bash.
With this i get the necessary informations from the mail:

```
cat $f | grep '^From' | head -n1 >> $TMPFILE
cat $f | grep '^Subject' | head -n1 >> $TMPFILE
```

but in some mails the subject is encoded like this

> Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Test:_Jaguar_XKR-S:_Unter_dem_Blech_lauert_d?=

How i can get the subject in correct encoding? I tried to use mail, mailx, mutt... but no one was able to simply load a mail from file.

Comment: FYI, no need for a pipeline: `grep -m1 '^FROM' $f >> $TMPFILE`

Comment: Or even `sed -n '/^\([Ff]rom\|[Ss]ubject\):/p;/^$/q' "$f" >$TMPFILE`; but if you are switching to Perl anyway, this is moot.

Comment: @chepner nice way, using less pipes is better, right?

Comment: @tripleee i'm scared of that regexp, but thanks for it. maybe i can use it later :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding in the Subject line looks like [MIME Words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Encoded-Word). One possible way to decode the data is write a perl script that uses the [MIME::Words](http://search.cpan.org/~dskoll/MIME-tools-5.503/lib/MIME/Words.pm) module. You could make the perl script a shell script and call it from your bash script.

convert_subject.sh:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 /usr/bin/perl -pe 'use MIME::Words(decode_mimewords); $_=decode_mimewords($_);'
```

Example of using the script:

```
$ echo "=?ISO-8859-1?Q?Test:_Jaguar_XKR-S:_Unter_dem_Blech_lauert_d?=" | sh convert_subject.sh
```

Which outputs:

```
Test: Jaguar XKR-S: Unter dem Blech lauert d
```

Comment: works pretty!  one small thing, the german umlauts are not converted correct. Any ideas? :) _Subject: Nur fÃŒr kurze Zeit: 15 Euro Gutschein fÃŒr_

Comment: working fine, failure of the umlauts is caused by my formatting of the mail as html and not fault of your little script. **THANKS**

Comment: Actually it looks like you have UTF-8 but viewing it in an ISO-8859-1 terminal (or other legacy 8-bit Western, could be Windows code page 1251 or etc).

Comment: i added `"Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'"` to the mail script, now the most umlauts are fine. just some here and there are now question mark in a box. any suggestions? my code: `(
  echo "Subject: Spam"
  echo "MIME-Version: 1.0"
  echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset='utf-8'"
  echo "Content-Disposition: inline"
  echo "<html><body><pre>"
  cat $TMPFILE
  echo "</pre></body></html>"
) | sendmail $i`

Comment: i figured out that lines starting with `=?utf-8?Q?` are working, lines with `=?iso-8859-1?Q?` get ? instead of umlauts.

Comment: working: `=?utf-8?Q?Top-_Reiseschn=C3=A4ppchen_+_Urlaubsgeld?=`. not working: `=?iso-8859-1?Q?K=F6rperliche_N=E4he?=`. executed over bash (echo "?..." | sh convert...)